# ElasticSearch results starting with a particular letter?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a large elasticsearch database full of records that each have a Name field, which is a single word. I would like to be able to page through the (sorted by Name) results starting at a particular letter. For example, I want to be able to start showing results where Name starts with the letter 'J', and then be able to page through all the remaining results.

This is how Name is currently mapped:

```
                   "Name": {
                      "type": "multi_field",
                      "fields": {
                        "name_exact": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "index": "not_analyzed"
                        },
                        "name_simple": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "analyzer": "simple"
                        },
                        "name_snow": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "analyzer": "snowball"
                        }
                      }
                    }
```

Is there a query that will let me do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [prefix filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-filter.html#query-dsl-prefix-filter) (cached by default) or [prefix query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html#query-dsl-prefix-query) (not cacheable).
Note that the query string itself is **not** analyzed.

If you want analysis on the query string, you should change your mapping and add an [edge-ngram](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html#analysis-edgengram-tokenizer) analyzed field; you can then use it with a [match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query).